# Cordova Xcode Deploy - CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for A

Tags: xcode, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, archive

I am building my app with Ionic and I have this error during the validation step, after archived.

> Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms
>   or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for A

In the log files, I can find this return:

> [myPath]/www/lib/phonegap-facebook-plugin/platforms/ios/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource

I tried to add the key CFBundleSupportedPlatforms in my .list file; used XCode 6.4; changed the target architecture, etc etc. Nothing works ...

Do you have any clues for me?

Thanks a lot

I am running under xCode 7.0.1 by the way.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error in xcode 7.1.  Any updates?

Comment: Hey Guys. Some help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the second comment.

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1110

The same thing happened to me the - plugin was somehow copied to the /www folder